# bad font rendering in sublime text 3 on macOS Mojave

Tags: sublimetext3, macos-mojave

After upgrading to macOS Mojave the font rendering in Sublime Text 3 is not working correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just reporting the answer stated [here](https://gist.github.com/MTuner) by MTuner

> Apple removed colored sub-pixel antialiasing in MacOS Mojave
>   (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/209/ starting from ~28min)
>
> To make fonts look normal in Sublime Text, add to Preferences:
>
> // For the editor
>
> "font_options": [ "gray_antialias" ],
>
> // For the sidebar / other elements
>
> "theme_font_options": [ "gray_antialias" ],

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the Tip!!

you saved my eyes... but unfortunately Sublime isn't the only software with an horrible font.

If you want to enable antiAliasing in all OS as before on High Sierra, you can run from Terminal the command:

> defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool FALSE